# Change Event Within Date Range

Tags: php, date

I am trying to write PHP code to check if a date/time falls within a certain range to render some HTML, and if it doesn't, render some other HTML. Below is my code. If I set the comparisons to a future date, it seems to work fine, & the flag status goes to half staff & then back to full staff according to the parameters. However the next day, about 2-3 hours after the status is set back to full staff, it automatically reverts back to half staff status.

```
if(date('Y-n-j-G-i') >= '2013-10-9-12-00' && date('Y-n-j-G-i') <= '2013-10-10-5-00' ) {

    echo "<span style='font-size:1.1em'>Governor's Flag Status:</br> <span style='color:#f00'>Half Staff</span></span>";
}
else {
    echo "<span style='font-size:1.1em'>Governor's Flag Status:</br> <span style='color:#333'>Full Staff</span></span>";
}
```

I have tried to 'think' through the logic, but it appears I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting format like `'2013-10-10-5-00'` from?

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare strings (as you actually do, because `date()` function returns formatted strings), compare UNIX timestamps instead.

Use [time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) with valid time format:

```
$currentTime = time();
if($currentTime >= strtotime('2013-10-9 12:00') && 
   $currentTime <= strtotime('2013-10-10 5:00')) {
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be working. It does make more sense to compare numerical values, than to compare strings. :)